# Installed magisk after LineageOS upgrade and now wifi doesn't work

Tags: lineageos, magisk, oneplus-7-pro, micro-g

I have a OnePlus 7 Pro. I had LineageOS 17 (Android 10) with microG, magisk, and vanced on it running just fine for almost a year. I upgraded the Android version to 11 first (which LineageOS documentation says is a pre-requirement) then I upgraded to LineageOS 18, and everything seemed to work just fine. I can confirm that my recovery and wifi worked.

A few days later I wanted to open Vanced YT, but it was no longer installed, then I noticed that magisk was no longer installed. So I installed it according to it's instructions which was basically using the app to patch the `boot.img` I got from the extracted files (from a payload-dumper) and then installed the produced `magisk_patched-24200_Y0Qmv.img`.

Ever since then is my problem. I can no longer turn on my wifi, I no longer have recovery mode, and every time I turn on/reboot the device I am greeted with a "System UI Crashed" error message. I can hit ok and everything else seems to work as expected. With the exception to my wifi not being able to turn on

What I've tried:

- re-flashed the original `boot.img`
- re-flashed the recovery image
- uninstalled magisk
- I tried re-flashing other images from the payload dump (modem.img, etc) the same way the LineageOS documentation said to upgrade and I get the following error

```
fastboot flash --slot=all modem modem.img
fastboot: error: Could not check if partition modem has slot all
```

I have no idea what that error means. Nothing changed. I'm still greeted with the same crash message. I still can't turn on my wifi. And I still can't boot into recovery mode.

To make sure I'm clear, my question is; "Where should I go from here? What things can I tell you in order to help me get my wifi working again, and to fix this 'System UI Crashed' error message?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what I did wrong. I basically patched the wrong `boot.img` so the kernel was mismatched. I patched the one from the OnePlus OxygenOS. Instead I needed to patch the one from LineageOS.

The steps I took in order to fix it was:

1. unzip the LineageOS zip
2. extract the payload with a payload dumper
3. copy the boot.img to my device
4. patch that boot.img
5. copy the magisk patched image which was produced from the magisk app
   to my computer with `adb` and `fastboot` on it
6. booted my android device into fastboot mode
7. flashed that magisk patched boot image to my device

After that when it rebooted, everything worked as expected with one exception; GCam. But I think this is related to the LinageOS upgrade. I was able to fix this by re-installing microG and upgrading to a newer version of GCam. All other original issues where cleared though. Wifi, phone, etc.

I hope this helps someone.